# Swift Codable Protocol. String encoding issue

Tags: json, swift, codable, encodable

Recently I have faced an issue while encoding an entity, which conforms to Codable protocol.

Here is the code for the Playground:

```
class Person: Codable {
    var name: String?
    var age: Int?
    var isDev: Bool?
}

let p1 = Person()
p1.name = "John N."
p1.age = 13
p1.isDev = false

let p2 = Person()
p2.name = "Jack"
p2.age = 19
p2.isDev = true

let people = [p1, p2]
let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(people)
let j = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])

print(j)
```

This is the output I am getting in the Playground console:

[image]

As you can see, the encoded p1 name has the quotation marks, but the p2 doesn't. So my question is why?

P.S. The only one thing I have noticed is that adding e.g. a space symbol or an underscore anywhere when setting the string value adds quotation marks in json. the p1.name contains a space, so it is encoded properly.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: You are printing a dictionary object. This has nothing to do with JSON or encoding but only with the way how objects are printed to console. Strings with a space are quoted, strings without space are not quoted.

Comment: That's just how it's printed when the value contains a space, you don't need to worry about it

Comment: thank you guys for your explanation. I have sent the encoded entity to one of the app endpoints, it does work properly despite the fact that it was printing like that in Playground

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`j` is the deserialised JSON object, not the JSON string (encoded data). If you want to see the JSON, convert `data` to a string, as *that* is the JSON:

```
print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
```

`j` is actually the representation of your JSON data using `NSArray`s and `NSDictionary`s. It turns out that if you print `NSDictionary`s with strings in them, quotes will be added to strings that have spaces and/or other special characters, to tell you where the string actually starts and ends.

Compare:

```
print(["name": "hello"] as NSDictionary)
print(["name": "hello world"] as NSDictionary)
print(["hello"] as NSArray)
print(["hello world"] as NSArray)
```

Output:

```
{
    name = hello;
}
{
    name = "hello world";
}
(
    hello
)
(
    "hello world"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer won't tackle the actual question, but I consider this is what the question author desires to achieve. In the posted code snippet, you are actually printing a dictionary, not a JSON string. You are doing the following things:

1. Convert the `Person` object into a JSON data
2. Convert the JSON data into a `Dictionary`
3. Print the dictionary

Recall that the JSON data is in fact the bytes representation of the JSON string.

You can check the JSON string just by doing this:

```swift
class Person: Codable {
    var name: String?
    var age: Int?
    var isDev: Bool?
}

let p1 = Person()
p1.name = "John N."
p1.age = 13
p1.isDev = false

let p2 = Person()
p2.name = "Jack"
p2.age = 19
p2.isDev = true

let people = [p1, p2]
let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(people)
let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)

print(jsonString ?? "invalid JSON data")
```